# How to do this Not In operation without triggering an overflow in the marker amount of operations in pyobdc/sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, ms-access, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

This is a simplification of the case:
I have two databases, a MySQL and a MS_Access. I am trying to delete all elements from the MsAccess that are not in the MySQL table but are still in MSAccess.
I am using sqlalchemy to connect to both DB. To connect with MSAccess (I know, this database should not be used anymore, this is actually part of a migration process), I am using [sqlalchemy-access](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access), that internally works with pyodbc.

The code that does this operation is:

```
#every row in the mysql table contains a field that references its correspondent row in msaccess
mysql_ids = mysql_session.query(mysql_table.id_msaccess).all()
list_of_ids = [elem(0) for elem in mysql_ids]

delete_query = delete(access_table).where((access_table).id.not_in(list_of_ids))
results = access_session.execute(delete_query)
```

However, I get this error message:

> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains -9972 parameter markers, but 55564 parameters were supplied)
> DELETE FROM [access_table] WHERE ([access_table].[id] NOT IN (?, ?, ... <here there are all the 55564 parameter markers>) parameters: (241, 242, 243,...)

I have found this issue in pyodbc's github page:

[Github Issue in Pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/250)

They essentially say that there is a marker counter that overflows in the internal implementation. They are talking about SQL Server but I guess the same thing happens here.

I could do this query in blocks of 32768 rows, or otherwise check for every element from the mysql table to see if it is in the ms-access table (I think this would be quite slow) but I wonder if there is not a better approach. Do you have any suggestions on how could I approach this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I strongly recommend doing this in Access. There, you can just link the MySQL table, and just perform a `DELETE * FROM Access_table a WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MySQL_table m WHERE m.ID = a.ID)`

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. It is a great idea. I am assuming you meant ```DELETE * FROM Access_table a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MySQL_table m WHERE m.ID = a.ID)```
Running this, if the changes from one table to the other are minor, it works. But if it has to delete a big part of the table, it gives me the following error:

```The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2 GB), or there is not enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result```

The access table has only 31 megabytes

Comment: Also, if I run this query directly in the Access table, it does work (although it takes a pair of minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could do this query in blocks of 32768 rows

That won't work for a NOT IN query. Say you had a list of rows to keep:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you tried to do that in batches of 3 then the first DELETE would be

```sql
DELETE FROM access_table WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

which would delete the rows with id values of 4, 5, and 6. Then the next DELETE would be

```sql
DELETE FROM access_table WHERE id NOT IN (4, 5, 6)
```

which would delete the rows with id values of 1, 2, and 3.

However, you could build a list of rows to *delete* like this:

```py
with mysql_engine.begin() as conn:
    mysql_existing = (
        conn.scalars(sa.select(mysql_table.c.id_msaccess)).all()
    )
    print(mysql_existing)  # [2, 3]

with access_engine.begin() as conn:
    access_existing = (
        conn.scalars(sa.select(access_table.c.id)).all()
    )
    print(access_existing)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

access_to_delete = list(set(access_existing).difference(mysql_existing))
print(access_to_delete)  # [1, 4, 5, 6]
```

and you could process that list in batches by using IN instead of NOT IN.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gord-thompson , it is great to find you here as well as in Github. I have tried the approach from the person in the comment first (@erik-a) and I have been only partially successful (works when the amount of elements to delete is small). I will try yours now.

Comment: I accepted your answer but forgot to reply, sorry. This approach was great and worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!